# HTML/CSS Tumblr: How to add a new line after each link in Masthead?

Tags: html, css

I am using a template for a tumblr theme: https://olleotathemes.tumblr.com/theme/oscar

I want to make each of the links on the masthead start on a new line instead of having them separated  by spaces, so it's easier to read. I am wondering if it's possible to do this.

So far I think the links are configured using CSS, and so far I found that masthead-navigation has an option to change the font size...
Part of the code is provided below, but the full code is provided in the link above.

```
article {
  padding: 5%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 15%;
  border-radius: .3em
}
.post-background article {
  margin: 5% 15%
}
.masthead-widget {
  padding: 1% 10%;
  text-align: center
}
.widgets {
  width: 100%
}
.widget {
  border-radius: .3em
}
.masthead-navigation ul {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
.hashtag {
  display: none
}
.post-tags a {
  border: 1px solid {
    color: Metadata links
  };
  padding: .3em 1em;
  border-radius: .3em
}
.post-title {
  font-weight: 700
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, #masthead {
  font-family: {
    text: Secondary Google Font name
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!
PS: I'm new at this, so thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code before `</head>`:

```
<style>
#masthead li {
  float: none;
}
#masthead nav a {
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
}
</style>
```

I got this result:

[image: The menu items are under each other]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Your code gave me a good start. I managed to separate the links into new lines by adding these: <style>
#masthead li {
  list-style:none;
  float: none;
}
#masthead nav a {
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 2em;
  display:block;
}

Comment: @VariaWill Oops, code `margin-right: 2em;` is unnecessary. It's my mistake. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @VariaWill In my opinion, `list-style:none;` and `display:block;` are not needed. These attributes are already set by the code of the page.